# How to get system time from website with Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am having a hard time getting the system time from a website

https://camping.bcparks.ca/ - so I stop getting beat out by other bots every day getting a campsite, I just want to take my kid camping this summer lol.

I got the overall script working and was happy.... until I realized this morning that my system time on my PC is .05s earlier than the website system time - so when it tried to reserve, it still went too early.

So, what I need, is a way to use the website system time instead of my local PC system time.

This is what I currently have using local time:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", resbutton)
target = datetime.datetime(2023,3,14,7,00,1)
def sleep_until(target):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    delta = target - now

    if delta > datetime.timedelta(0):
        time.sleep(delta.total_seconds())
        return True
sleep_until(target)
resbutton.click()
```

What I need is a way to have the now and delta based off of the website time.

I tried using

```
now = driver.get((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='systemTime']"))
```

But this didn't seem to work either maybe because the span for the time hasn't been clicked on? I am obviously new to all this but hopefully someone can lend me a hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://camping.bcparks.ca/")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "systemTimeButton")))
element.click()
element1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@aria-label,'The local time is')]")))
print(element1.text)
```

**Console Output:**

9:01:49 a.m.

Process finished with exit code 0

**The above code prints the below time:**

[image]